# Android Studio live preview requires project rebuild

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I decided to make an application on jetpack compose but when I download the Android Studio canary version 2021.1.1.1 and I try to write some code to see the changes on the preview at the right the preview tab says *the preview is not up to date* (or something like this) and requires a full project re-build to let me see my code changes

Comment: Yeah it's normal afaik,  live preview aka literal is only available for primitive types , density modifier check out https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/02/announcing-jetpack-compose-beta.html?m=1

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu Thanks a lot for the comment, can you explain to me in more detail do you mean in an answer? :-)

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu so there is no way to see your UI changes on the preview tab if you don't re-build the whole project?

Comment: Yes, this is like taking several steps backwards.  Reminds me of the days before there was any preview at all for our xml layouts--you had to compile and run your project to preview it.  I'm so glad google decided to make our lives easier by forcing us to do this again!

Comment: But oddly, the live preview change is almost instantaneous on the mobile app! For example, if you change padding value, you need to rebuild to see preview on your desktop, but you will notice that padding has changed instantly on the running app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of May 2022, There is no solution.  Sorry!

Perhaps someday this will change.  Until then, if you use jetpack compose, you'll have to do a rebuild your entire project to see the tiniest change in layout.

Furthermore, the requirement that you essentially have to write all your composable functions twice to preview them doubles the amount of boilerplate code you have to write and nearly guarantees that there will be code differences between the preview and actual behavior.  Can you say, "Extremely easy to introduce bugs"?  I thought you could.

For now, I recommend sticking with the old xml layouts.  At least your work flow will be a lot faster.  jetpack compose is simply not ready yet.

Comment: I find this answer quite subjective and inaccurate.

Why do you need to "write all your composable functions twice to preview them"? You write your composable function, and **call that composable function** from a Preview. That sounds a bit like writing a test, if you ask me.

You shouldn't need to rebuild your **entire** project, just the compose bits if you have the proper tooling dependencies added. Later AS releases, like Electric Eel, also include much better support for live edit, which alleviates this need.

Comment: this answer should not be accepted as correct. as stated by the first commentator, he is very subjective, while the assessment is based on non-compliance with the banal principles of coding. in a normal project, the minimum screen preview will take no more than 4 lines of code, taking into account brackets and annotations, just call the function, and do not write everything twice.

Comment: besides, this recommendation does not justify itself in any way, for example, what about such a task as a different design for different screen densities and API versions? if you do this with xml you will write hundreds of identical lines and updating the design will be hell because you have to update not in one place but in all xml files. with compose you use a declarative approach and there will never be such a problem (unless of course you use compose correctly)

Comment: @tasjapr et rharter:  Please feel free to supply a better answer.

Comment: Modularising you project can help in reducing the build time required. Noted that it is way easier said than done. But if you are building a new UI it helps to build your libary of UI components in a separate module.

Answer (score 1):

To have the compose live preview running on all features
as stated on the documentation

> Starting with Android Studio Electric Eel, you can see live updates to your composable preview as you make your edits.

1. Update your AndroidStudio too a version above `Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1`
2. Update your `Gradle Plugins` to the latest version recommended after installing
3. Do `Invalidate Cache and Restart`
4. Build the project

Reference 1:
[Jetpack Comp Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/previews)

Reference 2:
[Live updates to your Compose Preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases/as-electric-eel-release-notes#compose-preview)